# Grouping recursive cycle by common person

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, cycle

I am quite new to PL/SQL and I am struggling with quest that I get.

I have Legal and Natural entities. Each legal entity can have some natural entities and these natural entities can be tied to 1 or more entities.

- Company A have disponent #1 and #2 and #3
- Company B have disponent #2 and #4
- Company C have disponent #4
- Company D have disponent #5
- Company E have disponent #6
- Company F have disponent #6

The result should show which companies are tied through some disponent together. In real the relations are more "deep" and complicated.
On my example the result should be something like this:

- Company A - Group 1
- Company B - Group 1
- Company C - Group 1
- Company D - Group 2
- Company E - Group 3
- Company F - Group 3

Example table in excel:

[image: pic]

I made 3 tables:

- SNAPSHOT_FO - contains FO_CLUID (ID of natural entity)
- SNAPSHOT_VAZBA - contains PO_cluid (ID of legal entity) and FO_cluid. This is the relations table.
- ODLITE - contains FO_CLUID (ID of natural entity) and KOD (group ID) - empty at the beginning. Should be the final table which I can then join to PO_cluid and get the result.

```sql
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_temp
(
   F_CL VARCHAR2(255) NULL,
   par NUMBER(5) NULL
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

DECLARE
  party NUMBER := 1;
  r NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN
FOR CLUID IN (select FO_CLUID from snapshot_fo  WHERE ROWNUM =1)
LOOP
INSERT INTO tbl_temp (F_CL,par) VALUES (CLUID,party);

        WHILE  ( r> 0 )
        BEGIN

            MERGE INTO tbl_temp tg
            USING  ((SELECT distinct FO_CLUID from snapshot_vazba where PO_CLUID in (
                                                        SELECT distinct PO_CLUID 
                                                        from snapshot_vazba
                                                        where FO_CLUID in (select f_cl from tbl_temp where kod=party)
                                                    ))
            ) src
                on (tg.FO_cluid =src.FO_cluid)
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT (F_CL, par)
                VALUES (src.FO_CLUID, party)               
        SET r = SQL%ROWCOUNT
        END;
        INSERT INTO odlite (FO_CLUID, KOD) VALUES (tbl_temp.cluid,tbl_temp.party);
        delete from snapshot_fo where fo_cluid in (select fo_cluid from odlite);
        truncate table tbl_temp;
        party := party + 1;
        r := 1;
    END Loop;
end ;
/
```

Then I will just join the table `odlite` ON `FO_cluid` to my `PO_cluid` table.
But the code doesn't work at the moment... and I don't know any other way how to do it.
If there is any easier way how to do it, please let me know :)

PS: I am not allowed to make temporary table in declare part because of restrictions in our company.

Thanks in advance!

ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER  Version 19.2.1.247

Comment: I was thinking also about Prior and Connect By, but I am not sure if it’s possible to use it for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare
  v_cluid varchar2(30 char);
  v_party integer;
  change_num integer;

  function get_party return integer is
    grp integer;
  begin
    select
      nvl(max(kod),0)
    into
      grp
    from
      snapshot_vazba;

    return grp;
  end;

  function get_cluid return varchar2 is
    v_cluid varchar2(30 char);
  begin
    select
      nvl(max(fo_cluid), 'XNA')
    into
      v_cluid
    from
      (
        select
          fo_cluid,
          row_number() over (partition by 1 order by count_f desc) as rn
        from
          (
            select count(1) as count_f, fo_cluid from snapshot_vazba where kod is null group by fo_cluid
          )
      )
    where
      rn = 1;

    return v_cluid;
  end;
begin
  v_party := get_party + 1;
  v_cluid := get_cluid;

  while (v_cluid <> 'XNA' )
  loop
    update
      snapshot_vazba
    set
      kod = v_party
    where
      po_cluid in (select po_cluid from snapshot_vazba where fo_cluid = v_cluid) and kod is null;

    update
      snapshot_vazba
    set
      kod = v_party
    where
      kod is null and
      fo_cluid in (select fo_cluid from snapshot_vazba where kod = v_party);

    change_num := sql%rowcount;

    while (change_num > 0)
    loop
      update
        snapshot_vazba
      set
        kod = v_party
      where
        po_cluid in (select po_cluid from snapshot_vazba where kod = v_party) and kod is null;

      update
        snapshot_vazba
      set
        kod = v_party
      where
        kod is null and
        fo_cluid in (select fo_cluid from snapshot_vazba where kod = v_party);

      change_num := sql%rowcount;

    end loop;

    commit;

    v_party := v_party + 1;  
    v_cluid := get_cluid;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This works :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the task correctly, but you probably need it

```
select t1.po_cluid, t2.kod
  from snapshot_vazba t1
  join odlite t2 on t2.fo_cluid = t1.fo_cluid
 group by t1.po_cluid, t2.kod
 order by po_cluid, kod
```

Then you can use merge, insert into select, for loop, or type in a collection and process it as desired

Comment: Welcome to SO Pavel. Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for you question greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In particular post DDL for all tables and sample data - all as text no images - and the expected results of that data. As far as your PS goes: GOOD your company is doing it correctly; at least for Oracle.

Comment: The table Odlite is empty at the beginning. I just showed how it should look at the end.

Comment: You need an aggregation attribute. Otherwise, it is difficult to display the data you want using link mapping

Answer (score 0):

```
select po_cluid, dense_rank() over (order by min(connect_by_root(rn))) kod
  from (select rownum rn, s.* from snapshot_vazba s) s
  connect by nocycle prior fo_cluid = fo_cluid or prior po_cluid = po_cluid
  group by po_cluid
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=932cc549d5318dc54823e15955697915)</sup>**

This query returns desired output, however I am afraid it's very heavy for your database if table is big. Expect performance problems. It cycles between company - disponent - company and finds min common value. `Dense_rank()` is used only to enumerate values in sequence.

Comment: Yes :/ I was thinking also about Prior and Connect By,but the data set is too big and complicalted for this. I have more than 70k Companies and some Companies have over 200 disponents and some disponents are connected to more than 200 Companies.. 
But thank you! This could definitely be the solutions for smaller datasets.